# What simple syntax can be used for rich text?

Tags: syntax, wiki, markup, richtext

I want in an application with a simple text input, enriched with some marks to include formatting or semantic labeling. I want the syntax as easy as possible and I want to include self-defined labels.

Example:
[bold]Stackoverflow[/bold] is a [tag]good[/tag] resource for programmers.

Tables would be needed too.

HTML/XML and LaTeX are mighty enough to allow this, but too complicated. Wiki-Syntax seems simple, but uses another symbol for each markup, has unclear quoting and every Wiki seems to have another syntax. For tables and similar stuff Wiki becomes very complicated.

Exists a language/syntax, that matches my needs or can be slightly changed to do so? Or do I have to invent something myself? In that case, do you have suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely do NOT invent your own.  There are plenty of simple markup languages already, and users HATE learning new ones.  Trust me on this!

I would suggest using one of the following:

- [Textile](http://www.textism.com/tools/textile/)
- [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)
- [BBCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode)

Make your decision based on your userbase, as well as what tools and parsers are available in your chosen language.  For my site, we went with Textile, but I've found that BBCode tends to be the language that most people already know.  However, this will vary with different user demographics.

Answer (score 2):

StackOverflow, along with several other sites, uses [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).  I think it will give you the best balance between features and simplicity.

Comment: I hadn't known about it either, until I heard Jeff mention it. I then learned that other sites (like www.reddit.com) use it as well

Answer (score 1):

Let me add **[ReStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html)** to the list.

An additional benefit of using it is given by the availability of **[ReStructuredText to Anything](http://rst2a.com/)** service that makes extremely easy to create HTML or PDF versions of the document.

As already pointed out there are a lot of lightweight markup languages (many are listed here: **[wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language)**), there should be no need of creating your own.